# Vim: changing/deleting up to the end of a "block"

Tags: vim, editor

When you have a block of text delimitated by brackets or quotes, you can use

```
ci"
da(
```

and so on to change that block of text. But is there a way to change or delete from the cursor to the end of that block (in the way `cw` does it for words)?

Comment: By "block" of text, do you mean a paragraph?

Comment: No, I mean something delimitated by quotes, brackets, braces, curly braces, and so on. I don't know what it's usually called.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Benoit's answer of using `t f T` and `F` is the best way that I know of. When it comes to deleting to the end of a parenthesised block you can use `])`. This will take into account any nested parenthesis. There is also a corresponding `[(`, `]}` and `[{`.

Comment: How are these motions called? I'd like to read about them in the vim manual.

Comment: There's not too much to read I'm afraid but you can find them with `:help [(`.

Comment: Thanks! `d]}` does exactly what I was looking for (delete from cursor to end of block).

Comment: Is there a way to do delete up to closing `]` (taking into consideration nested `[]`) as well? d]] does not seem to work

Answer (score 30):

Use `ct)` to “**`c`**orrect **`t`**ill closing parenthesis”.

Vim motions with t, f, T and F are very, very useful. `:help t`, `:help f`.

**Update:** If there are nested parentheses where you are:

- ``` vi)o`` ``` will select till closing parenthese (will select inside parentheses, then switch to other end of the selection and move it to where you were (``` `` ```)
- ``` vi)`` ``` will select till opening parenthese (same mechanism, but without needing `o`)

The first one works only because when you are doing `vi)` a cursor jump is remembered, and ``` `` ``` goes to previous cursor location. It seems that `o` in visual mode does not affect this.

Comment: A detail: there is a slight difference with the original question, I guess, as this will apply to the immediate next closing parenthesis, whereas `vi(` for instance would look for the matching one. E.g., typing `vi(` while on the `x` in `(text (more))` would also select `(more)`, while typing `vt)` will fail to select the first closing parenthesis.

Comment: @Philippe: do you have a solution that does exactly the right thing?

Comment: In Philippe's example, `vf)` selects `xt (more)`. `v2t)` would do the same thing but with too much counting and typing for my taste.

Comment: Now I'm wondering why the hell these extremely useful commands and motions are nowhere to be found inside `vimtutor`, 7 years later.

Answer (score 6):

See the "[Text object selection](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select)" section of the Vim help.  You can define the selection sequences there with delete and change operations.  It shows how to select blocks delimited by any of the following (and more):

- `{}`
- `()`
- Quotes (`' or "`)

For example:

`d}` and `c}` will delete and change from the cursor to the end of the paragraph.

Comment: THIS is awesome. Almost forgot about that one, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a generic way to do what you want but, assuming you are on the `k` in:

```
The (quick (brown) fox) jumps over the lazy dog.
```

- `v2t)` would select:

  ```
  (The quick (brown) fox) jumps over the lazy dog.
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

  If you don't want to count you can chain `t)` to expand your selection: `vt)t)` would first select:

  ```
  (The quick (brown) fox) jumps over the lazy dog.
           ^^^^^^^^
  ```

  then:

  ```
  (The quick (brown) fox) jumps over the lazy dog.
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```
- `vT(` would select:

  ```
  (The quick (brown) fox) jumps over the lazy dog.
   ^^^^^^^^^
  ```

Comment: I like this answer the most but I think it is missing `vi)`, `v])` and `v[(`. Definitions are as follows:
1. `vi)` - select in ) block.
2. `v])` - select until end of ) block.
3. `v[(` - select until start of ( block.