# Vim: select/delete/change up to a param that can be in the next line

Tags: vim

Assume that I have such file:

```
f(arg1, arg2,
  arg3, arg4)
```

I would like to be able to select from the end of `arg2` till the closing bracket. If they were in the same line, I'd do: `vt)`. How to do it when the cursor=start of selection is in an earlier line then the final bracket?

The question is similar to [Vim: changing/deleting up to the end of a "block"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152454/vim-changing-deleting-up-to-the-end-of-a-block) and [Can you grab or delete between parentheses in vi/vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405415/can-you-grab-or-delete-between-parentheses-in-vi-vim), but is not a duplicate of these.

Comment: You do `v/)<CR>`.

Comment: Promote to answer?

Comment: btw, is there an inclusive version like `t` vs `f`?

Comment: Yes, `/pattern/e<CR>`.

Comment: It's `v/)/e-1` in that case -- oddly enough, .`\ze` doesn't seem to work.