# Vim: How to delete to closing square bracket in nested block

Tags: vim

I have a long nested list in Python:

```
[{'name': 'John', 'args': [[1], [165], [22]]},
{'name': 'Tom', 'args': [[2], [180], [28]]},
...
{'name': 'James', 'args': [[143], [174], [45]]}, # Delete from here on
...
{'name': 'Ron', 'args': [[298], [199], [38]]}]
```

and want delete from somewhere in the middle until the closing bracket. If I had a similar nested block with round brackets or braces, I could use `d])` or `d]}`. That works as expected, but `d]]` not. Unfortunately `f, t` are also no good options, because of the nested structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, you could do:

```
d/}]
```

(and hit enter) to delete until the search pattern: }]

In general, using search as a motion is my goto when I can't quickly see a built in motion/text object situation. You can even replicate the f/t distinction by using the {pattern}/{offset} functionality. E.g.

```
/{pattern}/s-
```

will move the cursor to just before the start of {pattern}.

:help search-offset

Comment: That is the most intuitive approach. In my case I extend the solution to `d/}\_s*]` in case there is space or a line break between `}` and `]`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
vi]o``d
```

to do the trick.

- `vi]` will select whole text within matching "]"
- `o` move the cursor to opening of matching "["
- ``` `` ``` move  cursor to last position
- `d` delete the selection

Credit to [Benoit's answer of Vim: changing/deleting up to the end of a “block”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152454/vim-changing-deleting-up-to-the-end-of-a-block#answer-8152609)

Comment: This also works, if I am outside of the inner square brackets. Sorry that I cannot mark both answers as solution.

Comment: No problem, just choose what you think may help others.